# Docker springboot app update war file without rebuilding using maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, docker

I am running Docker for Windows `version 1.12.3` and have a spring boot application running in a Docker container.

I'm using a maven container to build my application.

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(cd)\trunk:/project maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 mvn clean package -f /project
```

Which works fine it builds my war inside truck, then I run a tomcat container. copy my war file into the container and my application runs on port 8080.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 8005:8005 -p8009:8009 -v $(cd)\trunk\target\myAPP.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war tomcat:8.0.38-jre8
```

Now if I make a change (small) in my code (like add a comment, or return hello "just an example") the only way I can see the change in my application is to run the maven container again (which takes about 5 mins or so) and then run the tomcat container.

Is there a way for me to just update the code (like the way Spring Tool Suite does it) and then run the tomcat container so it picks up the changes in my code?

Comment: Not easily, given your current workflow, no.

Comment: OK can you suggest another way?

Comment: You don't really benefit from running your code in a container in your local dev environment. You should be relying more on automated testing rather than exploratory.

Comment: we were thinking along the line of, the machine that builds the code doesn't need maven on it as long as docker is installed, but maybe that is over kill?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. By container I meant Tomcat, or any other JEE container or webserver. You should only have docker installed on your build machines, then build and use a standard docker image that has java and maven in it for all your builds, no matter where they are performed. On your local dev machine however you need to also install a jvm and an IDE, then you can run tests against your code (your unit-tests), which should be black-box and which should not ever go through the server container.